# SXA 1.8 Sitecore 9.1 Azure Search field limit reached on default install

Tags: sxa, azure-search

In an Azure PaaS XP Single installation of Sitecore 9.1 using Azure Search, I have installed SXA 1.8. This has pushed the Sitecore Master index field count to just over the 1000 field limit in Azure Search.

Can anyone offer guidance as to what additional fields can be safely excluded other than those which are already excluded by the existing 9.1 configs ?

Comment: similar question. Please follow the below link  https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15796/azure-search-1000-field-limit-issue?rq=1

Comment: Deleting the index in Azure and rebuilding it caused the field count to drop below the 1000 limit.